# How to get python list element that contains 2 elements from another list

Tags: python, list, cryptocurrency

```
list_a = ['BTC', 'ETH', 'ADA', 'DNT']
list_b = ['ab', 'BTCETH', 'ADAETH', 'DNTBTC', 'DNTXXX', 'BTCOOO']

result = ['BTCETH', 'ADAETH', 'DNTBTC']
```

The problem is as above, I have two lists and the second list contains various concatenated trading pairs from the first list. I want to only find the trading pairs (elements in list_b) that both appear in list_a. Thanks

Comment: In the example, the elements of `list_a` all consist of 3 letters and the elements of `list_b` of 6 letters, would that always be the case? (that is, for the cases you're interested in, not strings like `'ab'` obviously)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very literal solution, regardless of the length of the strings in `list_a`:

```
list_a = ['BTC', 'ETH', 'ADA', 'DNT']
list_b = ['ab', 'BTCETH', 'ADAETH', 'DNTBTC', 'DNTXXX', 'BTCOOO']

result = [s for s in list_b if any(s.startswith(a) and s[len(a):] in list_a for a in list_a)]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['BTCETH', 'ADAETH', 'DNTBTC']
```

If you want to avoid duplicates (e.g. 'BTCBTC'):

```
result = [
    s for s in list_b 
    if any(s.startswith(a) and s[len(a):] in list_a and s[len(a):] != a
    for a in list_a)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have many combinations and a lot of trading pairs, then you cold do something like this:

Calculate the set of all possible pairs. If this is done often you could store this data on disk.

Then filter `list_b` using your set.

```
from itertools import permutations

list_a = ['BTC', 'ETH', 'ADA', 'DNT']
list_b = ['ab', 'BTCETH', 'ADAETH', 'DNTBTC', 'DNTXXX', 'BTCOOO']


trading_pairs = set()
for (a, b) in permutations(set(list_a), r=2):
    trading_pairs.add(a + b)


print([b for b in list_b if b in trading_pairs])
```

If `list_b` has all unique values, you could calculate the intersection:

```
print(set(list_b) & trading_pairs)
```

As a one-liner:

```
print(set(list_b) & set(map(''.join, permutations(set(list_a), r=2))))
```